# Ocamlfind cannot find package 'zmq'

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamlfind

I was trying to compile Ocaml tools as part of the [Quantum Package 2](https://quantum-package.readthedocs.io/en/master/). The error prompts me

```
[2/3] Compiling OCaml tools
make: Entering directory '/home/parallels/qp2/ocaml'
ocamlbuild -j 0 -cflags "-g" -lflags "-g" -ocamlopt "opt -O3 -remove-unused-arguments -rounds 16 -inline 100 -inline-max-unroll 100" qptypes_generator.byte  -use-ocamlfind 
Finished, 0 targets (0 cached) in 00:00:00.
+ ocamlfind ocamldep -package zarith,zmq,str,sexplib,ppx_sexp_conv,ppx_deriving,getopt -modules qptypes_generator.ml > qptypes_generator.ml.depends
ocamlfind: Package `zmq' not found
Command exited with code 2.
```

So I used `ocamlfind list` to see whether I had installed zmq. Initially I hadn't so I used `opam install zmq`, but after that zmq was still not on the list, and the error persisted.

So I git cloned from [here](https://github.com/issuu/ocaml-zmq) and did a manual install. The process was fishy (makefile didn't contain any directories) but after which zmq appeared in the ocamlfind list. Yet in compilation it still prompted me with the original error.

I am guessing I need to sort of tell ocamlfind where zmq package is but that is exactly of what I have no idea.

Comment: `ocamlfind query zmq` will tell you where the zmq package is installed.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an issue with multiple ocamlfind installed. You should check which `ocamlfind` is in path with

```
which ocamlfind
```

if the command doesn't return a path in your `QP_Root`, you probably want to:

- First, initialize your environment with `eval $(path_to_local_opam env)`
- Second, install ocamlfind with `opam install ocamlfind`.
- Third, check that `zmq` is visible with both `opam` and `ocamlfind`